# Redirect to Literal route by its name from Module.php

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm doing `Acl` in my `Module.php` and i'd like to redirect users to a specific route if they are unauthorized.
My route is `Literal` and is parameterless (i.e., has default controller and action params set in config).

I just can't find a way to do so.

Actually i know i can set controller and action params of my `RouteMatch` (i get it from the `MvcEvent`) but i want to set a new route by its name and without setting params.

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the function definition where you want to redirect from.

1. One could be a simple and direct `onBootstrap` -> `on Dispatch`, a function definition -

Eg:

```
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;
.....
........

class Module {

    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        $e->getApplication()->getEventManager()->getSharedManager()->attach('SOME_CONTROLLER OR * (-> all controllers)', 'dispatch', function($e) {
            $controller = $e->getTarget();
            if (unauthorized_user) {
                $controller->plugin('redirect')->toRoute('ROUTE_NAME');
            }
        }, 100);
    }
    ......
    ........
}
```

2. Other could be `onBootstrap` -> `on Route` -

This gets tricky because the function gets executed even before the route is finalized and so you don't have a `$e->getTarget()` i.e. Controller object yet.

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e) {
    $e->getApplication()
            ->getEventManager()
            ->getSharedManager()
            ->attach('*', 'route', function($e) {

        if (unauthorized_user) {
            return $this->customRedirect($e, 'ROUTE_NAME');
        } else {
            return $this->customRedirect($e, 'ROUTE_NAME', 'ACTION_NAME');
        }
    }, 100);
}

public function customRedirect($event, $route, $action = '') {
    $url = $event->getRouter()->assemble(array('action' => $action), array('name' => $route));

    $response = $event->getResponse();
    $response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Location', $url);
    $response->setStatusCode(302);
    $response->sendHeaders();
    exit();
}
```

Just in-case to get the current route_name, controller_name and action_name.

Can use this -

```
$sm = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
$router = $sm->get('router');
$request = $sm->get('request');
$matchedRoute = $router->match($request);
$params = $matchedRoute->getParams();

$route_name = $matchedRoute->getMatchedRouteName();
$controller_name = $params['controller'];
$action_name = $params['action'];
```

I hope it helps someone.

Comment: Sending headers in combination with $router->assemble() seems the best approach to me - i'll try it and mark this as an answer if everything works as expected

Comment: OK it works, thank you! I didn't know about the assemble() method of the router